# Getting Error as "Error occurred during SQL query execution "

Tags: sql, sqlite

Error while running the following script

> Error: Error occurred during SQL query execution
>
> Reason:
> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "SET": syntax error)

Script for test data creation:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @counter int = 1

WHILE (@counter <= 100)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @deptno number = 'deptno ' + RTRIM(@counter)
    DECLARE @name varchar2(50) = 'ABC ' + RTRIM(@counter)
    DECLARE @location varchar2(50) = 'xyz' + RTRIM(@counter) + '-USA'
    
    INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS 
    VALUES (@deptno, @name, @location)
    
    SET @counter = @counter +1
    
    IF (@counter%10 = 0)
        PRINT RTRIM(@counter) + 'rows inserted.'
END;
```

Comment: You've tagged *mysql* but your error is "SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR]"...

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/15332650/stu - Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: The client, DBeaver, is irrelevant. Tag the *DBMS* you're using.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit - Just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqLite doesn't support variables like in that script.
*(Which looks like a T-SQL script)*

But you can generate those records also via a recursive CTE.

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE RCTE AS (
>   SELECT 1 as n
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT n+1
>   FROM RCTE
>   WHERE n < 100
> )
> INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS (
>  deptno, 
>  name, 
>  location
> )
> SELECT n AS deptno
> , ('ABC ' || n) AS name
> , ('xyz ' || n || '-USA') AS location
> FROM RCTE;
> ```

> ```
> select * from DEPARTMENTS order by deptno desc limit 3;
> ```

| deptno | name | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | ABC 100 | xyz 100-USA |
| 99 | ABC 99 | xyz 99-USA |
| 98 | ABC 98 | xyz 98-USA |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=efb3d6df14acb25ba81d5605d755c25d)*

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003419/lukstorms - This worked. Thank you so much. :)